How to get rid of these lines from all software's after i made changes in Nvidia graphics settings?
I have changes my Nvidia GPU settings from nvidia control panel and after that i started seeing these lines in every software. Please explain how to get rid of these lines?
See the lines overall in software

Change the settings back ¬_¬

Might be Image Sharpening on the Adjust Desktop Color Settings page. You can also click the Restore Defaults link in the top-right corner of any Nvidia Control Panel page.
